# Detecting specific value of variable when polling at a time interval

Tags: c#

I am working on an application that monitors cars racing around a track (timing) and I need to record the number of times a car passes through the pit lane.

I have code to detect when a car is in pitlane and the position of the car on the track is recorded through a variable called splinePosition which is a float from 0.00000 to 1.00000. Car Position on track (splinePosition) is passed from the game to my application every 250ms.

I wanted to add to a PitStops variable each time a car is travelling through the pitlane and passes splinePosition 0.00000 which is the start/finish line. I tried this...

```
        else if (CarLocation == CarLocationEnum.Pitlane)
        {
            LocationHint = "PIT";
            if (Math.Abs(splinePosition) == 0)
                PitStops += 1;
        }
```

The problem is that my current code is unreliable, as when the car is travelling at speed in the pitlane and crosses splinePosition 0.00000, at one 250ms interval the splinePosition may be 0.99000 (just before start/finish line) and the next it may be 0.01000 (just after start finish line), so never increments the PitStops variable as it never sees 0.00000. If I add a condition for a range it can sometimes increment the PitStops variable twice or more depending on the speed of the car (i.e. it might be in that range for more than one 250ms interval).

What is the correct way to fix this?

Comment: Maybe keep track of where the car was before, and where it is now. If you pass through zero, increment the counter.

Comment: In addition to the suggestions for detecting the fact that the position has decreased you might also want to sample the time before and after and interpolate *when* the car would have crossed the line in order to get the lap time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd figure out something like this:

```
public class Class
{

    private double _prevPosition = 0;

    public void Sample(double splinePosition)
    {
        int prevLane = (int)Math.Floor(this._prevPosition);
        int currLane = (int)Math.Floor(this._prevPosition + splinePosition);
        int numberOfPitstops = currLane - prevLane;
        if (numberOfPitstops > 0)
        {
            //do whatever
        }
        this._prevPosition += splinePosition;
    }

}
```

On every Sample call (i.e. poll result) the function calculates the difference between the current lane and the previous one. Unfortunately, the reliability of this approach is limited to the interval of the polling: you should guarantee that the function is called at least once per lane.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This solution does work but ran into other issues related to the game and splinePosition in different scenarios. I will be able to use this same logic though to work around it in another way. I will mark this as the solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If the car cannot go around the track in the time interval then all you have to do is check if CurrentPos < LastPos.